# How get fields from children components for parent form?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular8, angular-forms

I have following structure:

*Parent component (**dialog**)*

```
<form #dialogForm="ngForm">
    <app-window-element></app-window-element>
</form>
<button (click)="button.callback(dialogForm)">Click me</button>
```

*Child component (**element**)*

```
<div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" formControlName="email">

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" formControlName="password">
</div>
```

And when click to button - send **#dialogForm**.

But I have problem - object **dialogForm** don't has fields from children-components. (*dialogForm is NgForm*)

And I get error:

> WindowFormComponent.html:5 ERROR Error: formControlName must be used
>   with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
>          directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
>   <input formControlName="firstName">
> </div>
>
> In your class:
>
> this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
>    firstName: new FormControl()
> });
> ```

If I have just fields within form - it is works, but is is don't work with children-components.

```
<form #dialogForm="ngForm">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" formControlName="email">

    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" formControlName="password">
</form>
<button (click)="button.callback(dialogForm)">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Partly. I need adding fields to parentForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the entire form to your child like this :

```js
parents.ts

constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.myGroup = fb.group({
    email: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl('')
  });
}

onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.myGroup.value);
}
```

```html
parents.html

<form [formGroup]="myGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <app-window-element [parentform]="myGroup"></app-window-element>
  <button></button>
</form>
```

```js
child.ts

@Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
```

```html
child.html

<div [formGroup]="parentForm">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" formControlName="email">

  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" formControlName="password">
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, I use this solution. How I can add children fields to myGroup? I keep getting errors: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive

Comment: I've updated my post adding the `parent.ts`. Are you sure about the name of your formGroup ?

Comment: I have situation, when parent don't know quantity and which fields exist in child.  Is it possible to add fields to the form inside the child?

Comment: With the solution I told you, the parent component must **declare** properties of form. If you want to manage form in a nested level, you should declare it into the child component.